# Teradata update statement

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I am trying to update column `A` of `TABLE1` by joining with `TABLE2` and finding the matching values of `TABLE1.B` and `TABLE2.C`

```sql
UPDATE TABLE1 
 from TABLE1 1,TABLE2 2
SET 1.A = 'Y'   
WHERE 1.B = 2.C;
```

The error message I am getting is:

> 'Column/Parameter'database.TABLE1.T1' does not exist.

This is the same error message I have been having. I have checked and the database and table names are all written correctly and do exist

Comment: The error message I am getting is: 'Column/Parameter'database.TABLE1.T1' does not exist. This is the same error message I have been having. I have checked and the database and table names are all written correctly and do exist

Comment: Don't qualify the columns in your set statement - `SET A = 'Y'`.

Comment: Wonderful. Thanks a lot Dnoeth and Andrew, you guys are amazing!!